# Pleroma nginx config taking over other server_name directives

Tags: nginx

I have several subdomains with different scripts and for some reason my Pleroma install, when enabled in Nginx, takes over at least 3 other subdomains. As soon as it's disabled though, it goes back to serving the subdomain it's supposed to. I've tried the default Nginx Pleroma config and modifying it to use my "shortcut" scripts.

For the sake of brevity, I posted the configs before and after enabling the Pleroma config [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/Valinwolf/ce026bc570f6e946fccd43a0367ada33). The first "file" of the gist is the output from `diff before.conf after.conf`, which I noted at the top of the file.

The default config can be found in the Pleroma repos, [here](https://git.pleroma.social/pleroma/pleroma/raw/develop/installation/pleroma.nginx). Note that I did change the domains and SSL locations in the default config to match my domains and paths, so that's not the issue. The sites.d config files are included in a double-wildcard manner using `include sites.d/*/*.conf`

So my question is... what is going on and how do I stop it from showing the wrong content when the Pleroma configs are enabled?

If you need any additional info, just let me know.

Comment: I've had similar problems when one of the other configs didn't `return` or `proxy_pass` in all possible cases and then falls through to some random config. Can you check the others and if possible post some of the other configurations as well?

Comment: @JensV every other config works perfect until pleroma gets enabled, but yeah I'll post my other configs.